# how to specify kafka brokers with KafkaIO in Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm trying to setup a KafkaIO pipeline but i can't figure out how to specify brokers.
Speficying brokername and port doesn't seem to do it. At no point am I specifying where my kafka cluster is:

```
       pipeline
            .apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers("broker.id__1:9092")
                    .withTopic("pageviews")
```

which gives me the error:

```
        Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)
...
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

My Kafka cluster is running locally and the broker id is correct.

What am i missing? What's the right way of specifying brokers?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's simply

```
withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
```